# Cómo conectar dos clientes por socket a un mismo server?

Tags: java, socket

Verán, tengo a mi clase Conexion la cuál tiene todo configurado, y mi clase cliente y mi clase Servidor.

Servidor:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Servidor extends Conexion //Se hereda de conexión para hacer uso de los sockets y demás
{
    public Servidor() throws IOException{super("servidor");} //Se usa el constructor para servidor de Conexion

    public void startServer()//Método para iniciar el servidor
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Esperando..."); //Esperando conexión

            cs = ss.accept(); //Accept comienza el socket y espera una conexión desde un cliente

            System.out.println("Cliente en línea");

            //Se obtiene el flujo de salida del cliente para enviarle mensajes
            salidaCliente = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());

            //Se le envía un mensaje al cliente usando su flujo de salida
            salidaCliente.writeUTF("Petición recibida y aceptada");

            //Se obtiene el flujo entrante desde el cliente
            BufferedReader entrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cs.getInputStream()));

            while((mensajeServidor = entrada.readLine()) != null) //Mientras haya mensajes desde el cliente
            {
                if( mensajeServidor.equals("salir")){
                    break;
                }
                //Se muestra por pantalla el mensaje recibido
                System.out.println(mensajeServidor);
            }

            System.out.println("Fin de la conexión");

            ss.close();//Se finaliza la conexión con el cliente
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Y mi clase Cliente:

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Cliente extends Conexion
{
    public Cliente() throws IOException{super("cliente");} //Se usa el constructor para cliente de Conexion

    public void startClient() //Método para iniciar el cliente
    {
        try
        {            
            //Flujo de datos hacia el servidor
            salidaServidor = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());

            //Se enviarán dos mensajes
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                //Se escribe en el servidor usando su flujo de datos
                salidaServidor.writeUTF("Este es el mensaje número " + (i+1) + "\n");                
            }           

            cs.close();//Fin de la conexión

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Desde dos clases Test (TestServidor y TestCliente) hice las pruebas, corrí primero TestServidor y el servidor arrancó y se puso a la espera del cliente. Luego corro TestCliente y muestra los mensajes que debe mostrar y cierra la conexión y ya. Si quiero volver a probarlo tengo que volver a correr TestServidor y TestCliente. Estas pruebas son en localhost.

Cómo le hago para que el servidor esté siempre escuchando y solo correr TestServidor una vez y TestCliente las veces que yo quiera?

¿Cómo puedo habilitar para que reciba más de una petición? Por ejemplo, que esté esté siempre arriba escuchando el servidor y yo desde otra computadora con otra ip llegarle?

Comment: Una pregunta podrías poner como es tu clase conexión

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que el servidor acepte múltiples conexiones lo habitual es seguir una estructura como esta

```
while (true) {
   cs = ss.accept();
   Thread hiloParaTratarElCliente = new HiloParaTratarElCliente(cs);
   hiloParaTratarElCliente.start();
}
```

Donde HiloParaTratarElCliente sería una clase que herede de Thread y que haga todo lo que tenga que hacer con el socket para tratar con el cliente.

```
public class HiloParaTratarElCliente extends Thread {
   Socket cs;
   public HiloParaTratarElCliente (Socket cs) {
       this.cs = cs;
   }
   public void run() {
       salidaCliente = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());
       // y el resto de tu codigo
   }
}
```